# Struts2 and weird action execution by javascript

Tags: javascript, struts2

I have an application to maintain, very old one, built with Struts and regular java  (no Spring stuff) in the back.
When I introduced a new page I noticed that the execution of actions run by java script is incorrect, I mean that the following script:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function addButtonClick(button) {
        var $suaName = $(button).closest("tr").find(".suaName").text();
        var $suaMobileNo = $(button).closest("tr").find(".suaMobileNo").text();
        $.post('viewSmsAccessCode!add.action', {name: $suaName, mobileNo: $suaMobileNo});
        window.location.href=createSmsAccessCode.action;
    }
</script>
```

executes the last line (redirection to another action) first and "viewSmsAccessCode!add.action" after.

This way my pages looses sync, new page is showing always the previously selected record. Above script is executed by button click (each row has its button in the DataTable.

```
<button class="formButton" onclick="addButtonClick(this)">Add</button>
```

This happens even when I move the last line to a separate script and called them like this:

```
<button class="formButton" onclick="addButtonClick(this);redirect('createSmsAccessCode.action')">Add</button>
```

Actions extends ActionSupport class and implements one or more of this interfaces: SessionAware, ServletRequestAware, Preparable

I really don't get it, how is that possible? What possibly can cause such behavior?

Alternatively how can I pass the parameters retrieved by my javascript to new action in synchronous way?

Comment: _What possibly can cause such behavior?_ -- The asynchronous nature of XMLHttpRequest (`$.post()`).

Comment: _ Alternatively how can I pass the parameters retrieved by my javascript to new action in synchronous way?_ -- This won't matter since you are loading a completely new page with `window.location`. When you do that, everything is reinitialized back to its starting state.

Comment: Fair enough, is it possible to make it wait until $.post() finish?

Comment: Yes, since you are using jQuery(?) you can use `$.ajax` with the `sync` setting rather than `$.post`. BUT, the same result will occur: 1) AJAX request will block and complete first, 2)  then the page will reload, 3) the initial state of the HTML will be shown. In other words, this won't change a thing. Your design (and thinking) must change.

Comment: all right, I changed the approach and remove window.location piece from javascript function and doing redirect in struts.xml instead the way that the method  I am calling will redirect to new page. The effect is the same, how do you explain this?

Comment: Rather than repeating myself for the 4th time I'll try a new approach. It is possible that you don't understand that there is no state maintained between the UI in the browser and the Struts backend. The browser UI will always start with a new, fresh state each time a page is loaded. If you don't change the state on the server prior to reloaded (redirect) the page, the same view will be shown every time the page is loaded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since there are no answers actually I decided to answer by myself in case someone else will struggle with similar thin.

Using javascript or rather JQuery to that kind of thing is not good idea due to its async nature. Much better is to stick to struts actions and what can be done with them. Initially I decided to use javascript because I didn't know how to determine which button (table row) is being clicked. However it is unnecessary at all. Instead of rendering the form with whole table inside it is better to generate separate form for each row so finding the row clicked is not required any more, like this:

```
<tbody>
        <s:iterator value="accessList" status="status" var="row">
            <tr>
              <s:form action="viewSmsAccessCode">
                <td class="suaName"><s:property value="suaName"/><s:hidden name="suaName" value="%{suaName}"/></td>
                <td class="suaMobileNo"><s:property value="suaMobileNo"/><s:hidden name="suaMobileNo" value="%{suaMobileNo}"/></td>
                <td><s:property value="suaActionList"/></td>
                <td style="width: fit-content">
                  <span>
                    <s:submit action="createSmsAccessCode" class="formButton" value="Add"/>
                    <s:submit action="deleteSmsAccessCode" class="formButton" value="Delete"/>
                  </span>
                </td>
              </s:form>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
</tbody>
```

Now obtaining parameters for details page requires no further steps, parent action just need both variables to be declared, no javascript involved at all.

So that's the "alternative way" I've been asking about.